# WordPress Form/Offline Credit Card/Coupon Plugin

Tags: php, forms, wordpress, plugins, credit-card

A client of mine is wanting me to use WordPress to develop their Web site and they have a requirement for a form that will take the user's name, address information, credit card information (to be processed offline), coupon information (if any) and calculate the total amount accordingly.

I have developed Web sites using WordPress before but never really played with any form plugins for it that much.  Is there a (customizable) plugin available that already offers the functionality I outlined above?

Any help is much apporeciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is a premium plugin called [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) that would be perfect for this.  I have a developer license and use it on every site that I develop, it is definitely worth the money.

Remember that if you are taking Credit Card information that you will want to encrypt that in the database, and ensure you have an SSL up and running on the site to secure both the form on the front-end and the admin area.  I have used [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/screenshots/) before.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  As for the CC info, do you mean simply using SSL during the transaction or actually storing an encrypted CC number in the DB?

I also take it that as far as the coupon code is concerned, I would have to code something custom to be able to manage them (i.e. not provided by default by Gravity Forms)?